# SQL - Join one subquery for multiple times within union

Tags: sql, performance, subquery, union

I have 4 different tables which store different transactions for users and I would like to union all of the transactions for some specific users. But the problem is, all these 4 tables have huge amount of data, therefore when I try to UNION all of them and JOIN with the users, it takes hours to compute. What I'm doing is:

```
SELECT blablabla
FROM transactions1 t1
JOIN users ON (users.id = t1.user_id AND user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey')
UNION
SELECT blablabla
FROM transactions2 t2
JOIN users ON (users.id = t2.user_id AND user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey')
UNION
SELECT blablabla
FROM transactions3 t3
JOIN users ON (users.id = t3.user_id AND user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey')
UNION
SELECT blablabla
FROM transactions4 t4
JOIN users ON (users.id = t4.user_id AND user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey')
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The problem is, I'm running 
`JOIN users ON (users.id = t1.user_id AND user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey')` this filter 4 times by joining each transaction table with users.

In order to have best practice and increase the efficiency of my query, how should I improve my query ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either select the "*user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey'*" from your users using a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) or into a temporary table.

Then use that result in your Union.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT blablabla
FROM transactions1 t1, transactions2 t2,transactions3 t3,transactions4 t4
JOIN users ON (users.id = t1.user_id OR users.id = t2.user_id OR users.id = t3.user_id 
OR users.id = t4.user_id AND user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey');
```

Comment: but the number of fields are always different in each transaction table, therefore I'm extracting different fields from each different transaction table

Answer (score 0):

Check if all fields with conditions are INDEXED. (t.user_id, users: state,friends,loc)
Also try to use this:

```
select blablabla from
(
  select * from user where user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey'
) U1
join transactions1 t1 on (U1.Id=t1.User_id)

UNION ALL

select blablabla from
(
  select * from user where user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey'
) U1
join transactions1 t2 on (U1.Id=t2.User_id)

UNION ALL

select blablabla from
(
  select * from user where user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey'
) U1
join transactions1 t3 on (U1.Id=t3.User_id)

UNION ALL

select blablabla from
(
  select * from user where user.state = 1 AND user.friends > 1 AND user.loc = 'Turkey'
) U1
join transactions1 t4 on (U1.Id=t4.User_id)
```